# Gradle finish with 552 errors

Tags: android, gradle

when i build the project i get this error "Gradle finish with 552 error " but there are no java code error app run perfectly

[Please click the link for the error](https://pastebin.com/tnAvRSyd)

```
Please see the link for the error
```

Comment: We cannot help you without code. Could you please post code?

Comment: You don't have 552 errors ! . You are using some sort of a dependency called ```EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent``` which do some funny things..

Comment: What can i do for that? @Infamous